# How To Trigger GitHub Reusable Workflow On Specific Condition

Tags: github, github-actions

I have a reusable workflow to run unit tests after each commit is pushed. However, I don't want to trigger it on each commit push now. Is there a way to run reused workflow when **Tag Created** or **Pull Request Opened | When New Commit Pushed To Pull Request**

## Reusable Unit Test Workflow

```
name: Reusable Unit Test

env:
    # This will suppress any download for dependencies and plugins or upload messages which would clutter the console log.
    # `showDateTime` will show the passed time in milliseconds. You need to specify `--batch-mode` to make this work.
    MAVEN_OPTS: "-Dmaven.repo.local=.m2/repository -Dorg.slf4j.simpleLogger.log.org.apache.maven.cli.transfer.Slf4jMavenTransferListener=WARN -Dorg.slf4j.simpleLogger.showDateTime=true -Djava.awt.headless=true"

    # As of Maven 3.3.0 instead of this you may define these options in `.mvn/maven.config` so the same config is used
    # when running from the command line.
    MAVEN_CLI_OPTS: "--batch-mode --errors --fail-at-end --show-version"

    # Override when additional goals are necessary (such as `package assembly:single`)
    MAVEN_ARTIFACT_GOALS: "test"

    # IMPORTANT: Only override in client project when strictly necessary
    # NOTE: The order here is important. prepare-agent must be done before running tests
    MAVEN_GOALS: "clean org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugin:prepare-agent $MAVEN_ARTIFACT_GOALS"

on:
    # does not work from here
    push:
        tags:
            - '*'
    pull_request:
        types: [ opened, synchronize, reopened ]
    # to here
    
    workflow_call:
        inputs:
            java-version:
                description: Java Version
                required: true
                type: string
            java-distribution:
                description: Java Distribution
                required: true
                type: string
            java-cache:
                type: string
            maven-image:
                description: Maven Image To Run Unit Tests
                required: true
                type: string
jobs:
    unit-test:
        runs-on: docker-runner
        container:
            image: ${{ inputs.maven-image }}
        steps:
            -   uses: actions/checkout@v3

            -   name: Set up JDK ${{ inputs.java-version }}
                uses: actions/setup-java@v3
                with:
                    java-version: ${{ inputs.java-version }}
                    distribution: ${{ inputs.java-distribution }}
                    cache: ${{ inputs.java-cache }}

            -   name: Build with Maven
                run: mvn -B ${{ env.MAVEN_GOALS }}

            -   name: Publish Test Report
                uses: actions/upload-artifact@v3
                if: success() || failure() # always run even if the previous step fails
                with:
                    name: unit-test-result
                    path: 'target/surefire-reports/TEST-*.xml'
```

## Main Workflow

```
name: GitHub Actions Demo
on: [ push ]

jobs:
    unit-test:
        name: Unit Tests
        uses: ./.github/workflows/run-unit-tests.yml
        with:
            java-version: '17'
            java-distribution: 'corretto'
            java-cache: 'maven'
            maven-image: 'maven:3-amazoncorretto-17'
    integration-test:
        name: Integration Tests
        uses: ./.github/workflows/run-integration-tests.yml
        with:
            java-version: '17'
            java-distribution: 'corretto'
            java-cache: 'maven'
            maven-image: 'maven:3-amazoncorretto-17'
            skip-unit-tests: true
```

Do I need to use `jobs.<job_id>.if`? If so, how?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. Removing `workflow_call` is not the correct way to use reused workflows. If you need separate jobs for different events, we should use `jobs.<job_id>.if` or use something like this where you call reused workflows

```
on:
    pull_request:
        types: [ opened, reopened, synchronize ]
    push:
        tags:
            - '*'
```